# Reference assemblies for .NETFramework not found (4.7.1)

Tags: debian, mono, deepin

I've recently set-up Linux on my pc (Deepin, a distro based on Debian).
In that fresh set-up distro, I installed VSCode and unity since I'd like to play around with game development. VSCode since I saw some warnings somewhere, I also went to install dot net from the official Microsoft website which seems to be an old version "3.1".

But even though .net is installed, I still get the following error when starting VSCode:

```
The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application.
```

From a quick google, I found that installing `mono` should fix that error, but it apperently didn't. I tried rebooting, going thorugh the install process again, but the error stil appears.

What am I doing wrong?

Im new to game developing as well as working on linux, I just want to play around with that stuff.

My `mono -V`:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 6.12.0.90 (tarball Fri Sep  4 14:03:37 UTC 2020)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug 
        Interpreter:   yes
        LLVM:          yes(610)
        Suspend:       hybrid
        GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)
```

My `dotnet --info`:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.402
 Commit:    9b5de826fd

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Deepin
 OS Version:  20
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         linux-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.402/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.8
  Commit:  9c1330dedd

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.402 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.8 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.8 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Answer (score 0):

You have installed dotnet core 3.1 but you want the .Net Framework.

dotnet core is the cross platform framework which runs on Linux. .Net Framework is AFAIK Windows only.

Not sure if this what you want but if you use Wine you can emulate it on Linux: [Install Microsoft Net Framework 4.7 In Ubuntu 18.04/18.10](https://curiousviral.com/install-microsoft-net-framework-4-7/)

Comment: Hmmm I see. What about mono, shouldn't mono have it included as well?

Comment: Sorry can't help you there. Try to search for a tutorial on how to install unity on Linux - I'm sure they'll also list all the required parts.

Comment: Alright, thank you anyways. I checked a lot of forums by now, they all say that mono is should be installed and then it works.. Look at this one for example, I match all the requirements: https://medium.com/@sami1592/set-up-visual-studio-code-for-unity-in-linux-69b7f4352e0b

Anyways, I want to try out Pop OS aswell, maybe I have more luck with that distro ^^